# Any php request return 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: javascript, php

I decided to write a small php script to send an email. And I ran into a problem - when I send a request via `$mail->send()` from PHPMailer class, I get a Bad Gateway 502. After that, the script freezes and does not respond to requests. Even if I change the code inside the emailSender.php nothing happens. Even the echo command does not work.

When I restart the local server, the script responds again, but returns 502 again. The data from the `$_POST["EmailRecipient"]` and `$_POST["Message"]` request comes correctly and is output through the echo correctly too. I can see it in the console.

Then I tried to make a request on google.com and again got 502 bad gateway.
What am I doing wrong? This is my first php code and I can't figure it out.

I ran all the files in one folder on the local host in phpstorm. Please explain what I am doing wrong. Below is my code.

```js
function processForm() {
    let emailRecipient = document.getElementsByName('EmailRecipient')[0].value;
    let emailMessage = document.getElementsByName('Message')[0].value;

    if (checkEmail(emailRecipient) && emailMessage) {
        let form = document.getElementById('emailForm');
        let formData = new FormData(form);

        postRequest('emailSender.php', formData);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        showMessage('You have entered an invalid email address!');
        return false;
    }
}

function postRequest(url, data) {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        body: data
    })
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(response => showMessage(response.text()))
        .catch(error => showMessage(error));
}

function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }

    return response;
}

function showMessage(responseText) {
    console.log(responseText);
}

function checkEmail(email) {
    let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="emailForm">
            <div>
                <p>To:</p>
                <input type="text" name="EmailRecipient">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Message:</p>
                <textarea name="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="SendEmail" onclick="return processForm();">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="formHandler.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
<?php

$emailRecipient = '';
$message = '';

if (isset($_POST["EmailRecipient"]) && isset($_POST["Message"])) {
    $emailRecipient = $_POST["EmailRecipient"];
    $message = $_POST["Message"];

    echo $emailRecipient;
    echo "\n";
    echo $message;
}

$sFile = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com"); // 502 bad gateway

echo "\n";
echo $sFile;
```

Comment: Sounds like problem could be with the proxy and not with your script. Maybe your script fails once and then the proxy just sends 502 without proxying the request?

Comment: Try https instead of http?

Comment: @Joel Harkes This is strange, because I don't use a proxy. This is what I get with an https request and any other: https://ibb.co/F7ZhTSk

Comment: `// 502 bad gateway`- the error comes from _your_ script, according to your dev tools screenshot. Go check out what the PHP error log has to say first of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really figured out the server setup and phpstorm. I thought that it automatically pulls up the server and its configuration during installation. Still, he ran simple scripts on localhost without requests normally. But it turned out that phpstorm needs manual configuration. So far I have found a way out for myself: work with the project from the server root folder. In my case, this is XAMPP and the path is C: \ xampp \ htdocs. If you run the project from there, then the requests go correctly. 
It seems that you can also configure mapping from an arbitrary directory.